# How to simplify logic checking if all cells in a record of array are null using for

Tags: java

Can this code to be simplifed using `for`?

```
if ((col[0] == null) && (col[1] == null) && (col[2] == null) && (col[3] == null) && (col[4] == null)){    
    //statement 
}
```

Comment: are u just checking upto 5 values, or is it large number?

Comment: What is your definition of simplified? Also, what exactly is your goal, are you performing a separate operation for each element depending on whether each one is non-null?

Comment: Wrap this into a method and loop through all the elements and return a boolean value from the method. Use the returned value for decision making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `boolean` flag:

```
boolean areAllNull = true;
for (int i = 0; i < col.length; i ++) {
   if (col[i] != null) { 
       areAllNull = false;
       break;
   }
}

if (areAllNull) {
    //statement 
}
```

If you want to limit only to certain positions in the array change `col.length` by a variable or constant marking the limit:

```
int numberOfPositions = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPositions ; i ++)`
```

Comment: it's work .. thnks ,,
but i think there's a little flaw ..

is it col ++ or i ++ ???

Comment: @PallyNainggolan totally agree it was `i++` corrected it. I wrote this code *on the fly* and parser was not complaining hehehe.... thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Java 8 feature with `Stream` API:

```
boolean allNull = Arrays.stream(col).allMatch(Objects::isNull);
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if X elements in an array are null, you cannot reduce the number of checks (X) unless you can short-circuit them.  However, you can have a cleaner "if" statement if you package it in a method:

```
if (isAllNull(col, 0, 4)){
    // do stuff
}

public boolean isAllNull(Object[] col, int start, int end){
    for (int index=start;index<=end;index++){
        if (col[index] !=null){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This will return false immediately when it finds one of the values not null.

Comment: `index` variable is declared twice, remove `int index = start;` is an useles line, declare it in the loop scope, is all you need